# How use custom IPasswordHasher?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I implements IPasswordHasher

```
public class MyPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher
{
    public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        using (SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create())
        {
            byte[] hash = mySHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password.ToString()));

            StringBuilder hashSB = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                hashSB.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return hashSB.ToString();
        }
    }


    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(
      string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        if (hashedPassword == HashPassword(providedPassword))
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
        else
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }
}
```

I write in IdentityConfig

```
manager.PasswordHasher = new MyPasswordHasher();
```

but  `var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);` in AccountController/Login do not use MyPasswordHaser.

How can I use it in Identity 2.1?

Comment: I have this working in Identity 3, which is different. You add this to Startup.cs:  
`services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>, MyPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>>();`

Answer (score 2):

You have to plug it into the UserManager:

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser, int>
{
    public AppUserManager(AppUserStore a_store)
        : base(a_store)
    {
        _container = a_container;
        _emailService = _container.GetInstance<IEmailService>();

        PasswordHasher = new AppPasswordHasher();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
PasswordHasher = new MyPasswordHasher();
```

in UserManager ctor!

Comment: This is 5 years old so might have been correct then, but not a good answer today. Should use DI.